# xcode 4 + phonegap ... not update JS upon build?

Tags: javascript, xcode4

I've run into a weird issue that has had me scratching my head for the past hour.

I'm working on an iPad app using Xcode 4 and PhoneGap. It's using jQuery. I've put all my JS into a scripts.js file.

Things are working well.

I spend about an hour doing a lot of CSS tweaking. I'd update the CSS file, stop the app, rebuild, and push to the iPad simulator or my iPad. That's been working fine. Every update to the CSS file is reflected on the new build.

I then needed to update the JS file. I couldn't get things to work and then I finally realized none of my JS changes were actually be put into the build. I finally blanked out my JS file completely, rebuilt, and it's still not updating.

The file I'm updated is being updated in the finder in the project folder (I can right-click 'view in finder' and that file is, indeed, updated).

So I'm stumped. Is the xcode compiler caching the JS file somehow instead of grabbing the updated file? Is there a way to force it to grab the updated JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after some more googling, this seems to be a common problem. Xcode seems to cache files even after you've edited them.

One option appears to be to run the 'clean' command before a new build. I tried that, no luck.

Other solutions appear to involve rebuilding the .plist file each time. I don't fully understand that (yet) in terms of how to do that automatically, but did find this workaround:

- Open your .plist file
- change something (in my case, I rename one of the app icon files each time)
- save and build

Doing that magically forces xcode to FINALLY grab all the updated files and do a proper build.

I can't explain why Xcode seems perfectly happy grabbing my updated .css file each and every time but won't update the .html or or .js files without first doing this .plist file edit.

Seems as if Apple still has a few bugs to work out. I guess we'll have to wait patiently for the next 4gig .x relase of it. ;)

Comment: This just worked for me (XCode 4.2.1, PhoneGap 1.3.0).  The "Clean Build Folder..." mentioned above did not work.

Now, subsequent JS changes are rebuild automatically.  I wonder if a `touch $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$INFOPLIST_PATH` pre-action shell script (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944185/how-to-get-xcode-to-add-build-date-time-to-info-plist-file) would do the trick for keeping this working normally.

Answer (score 10):

I found it necessary to hold the Option button when clicking the menu command which turns the command from "Clean" to "Clean Build Folder..." and this caused my assets to be refreshed.

Comment: I didn't even know the option button changed the drop down menu actions! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a new "Run Script" build phase to your target in XCode and paste this :

```
touch -cm ${SRCROOT}/www
```

Comment: This works like a charm. To support directories with spaces, one should add quotes around the last parameter.

Comment: This is built into PhoneGap now (at least in 2.1.0)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have mac right now, but few things to try:

- Try to look at Your project build (or prebuild or something) action where www folder is supposed to be copied.
- Try to change index.html and see if it works.
- Try to copy paste all Your javascript code to index.html script tag
- Try to validate Your javascript (For example: Google Closure Compiler) and see if it has no problems

Comment: Does Xcode/Phonegap try and validate a .js file before compiling? That could be it. Let me run it through JSLint...

Comment: No it doesn't. It just copies whatever You have written. It compiles just Obj-C wrapper that allows iOS to run phonegap. Phonegap does no js compilation/conversion. It is a little bit annoying, especially if You are used to development environment with firebug and friends.

Answer (score 2):

None of these worked for me :(

The only way  I can get the thing to update its html and js is by running a "corodova run ios" at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Find the file called `copy-www-build-step.sh`.

Mine was in `[project_folder]/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh`

In that file, find the lines beginning `rsync -a "...`

Add -c to the rsync lines, so they ready `rsync -a -c "...`

copy-www-build-step.sh is the script that copies the files over from www/ to where they go inside the app file. rsync is the unix file copying command they use. Without that -c, rsync just compares the file size on each file and folder and copies them over if the size has changed, and a couple of spaces or quotes don't count as enough of a change. With the -c, it checksums them and compares the checksums, which will catch even the smallest changes.

I think this will work best, because it's not a workaround, it actually fixes the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, and the build phase command posted here (which is actually now used by the default Phonegap project) did not work for me, since I am editing my files on a Parallels Windows VM, in Visual Studio.

What I did, was use this instead, in the Build Phase of my project:

```
find "${PROJECT_DIR}/www/." -exec touch -cm {} \;
```

Thats basically a recursive touch. I then set up Visual Studio to always reload the file, if it has been saved. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which did it, but I did the following:

1. Changed an icon value in my `MyProject-Info.plist`
2. Quit the simulator
3. `Product -> (hold option) -> Clean Build Folder`
4. Run

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with the iOS Simulator, I tried most of the suggestions above with no success, it would not pick up my changes.
Later another possible solution occurred to me, which did work:

Delete the app from the simulator. (ie. Click and hold on the icon, then hit the X when it starts to shake, then Hardware Home)
Then re-run from xCode.

(NB: "cordova build ios" was also required)

Answer (score -1):

Nothing solution of above work
finally i saw there are two index.html file and .js file in the project created using Command line tool of Cordova

So make changes as below shown under **Staging folder**
[image]