# xcode 4 + phonegap + sencha touch … not update JS upon build?

Tags: xcode, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a similar issue to [xcode 4 + phonegap ... not update JS upon build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486139/xcode-4-phonegap-not-update-js-upon-build/7101636#7101636) but with the inclusion of Sencha Touch.

The problem is html changes are recognized but changes to javascript files are not seen when running the app in the simulator. Here's a quick list of suggestions made in the post listed above, none of which worked for me:

- update and save .plist
- touch www
- clean project (Command+Shift+K)
- clean build folder (Command+Shift+Option+K)

Deleting the app from the ios simulator and relaunching works but that quickly becomes a hassle. Sencha Touch takes care of its own caching using localstorage. Even though they give you the ability to define the caching strategy in app.json, I haven't found a configuration that works.

Here are the versions I'm using.

- XCode - 4.3.2
- PhoneGap - 1.6.1
- Sencha Touch - 2.0.1 FINAL

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly i think it has something to do with HTML5 application cache. Take some time to study a little on how HTML5 Application Cache works [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

The reason your changes are not being reflected is maybe because the hash values in the app.cache file is not being changed... For the js file you wish to get changed change the hash value in comments to anything you want... This would ensure that the browser does not read the HTML & JS files from the cache but would rather download the new updated version...

When you are reloading the page in browser open the console you would get an idea of the updating process...

Hope it helps...