# Phonegap Jquery Mobile Saving Data to Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Im trying something simple below. I want to accept user input for their name click a button save it and when the app loads a second time it displays the name.

Where am I going wrong below?

Do i need to put this code block somewhere else?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
});
    $('#newpage').live('pageshow', function() {
        var personName = window.localStorage.getItem("name");
        if(personName.length>0){
                $('#name').val(personName);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Full html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
});
    $('#newpage').live('pageshow', function() {
        var personName = window.localStorage.getItem("name");
        if(personName.length>0){
                $('#name').val(personName);
        }
    });

});
</script>


<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            Home Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        hello Phone Gap and JQuery Mobile! <a href="#newpage" data-role="button">new page</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>
            footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="newpage" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            new Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="name">what is your name?</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" />
        <a id="saveButton" href="" data-role="button">Save</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>
            footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to place the button click event hookup in the `pageinit` event - they even specify this in the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html)

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#newpage",function(){
    $('#saveButton').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem("name", $('#name').val());
    });
});


$(document).on('pageshow','#newpage', function() {
    var personName = localStorage.getItem("name");
    if(personName.length>0){
            $('#name').val(personName);
    }
});
```

**For iOS device testing:** In case your changes do not reflect on your device, make sure to `touch` your files before you deploy. Phonegap's default project template already does this, but their command does not work for me. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707386/561545

Comment: Thanks for giving that a shot. I recompiled and It still does not save my name. After i revisit the app it does not display yet.

Comment: Make sure the recompiled files are actually being copied, I had trouble with this once - you really want to check that. :)

Comment: See my edit - apologies, forgot to move the pageshow event :)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work when I test in Chrome but when i push to an apk and test on phone it does not save my name.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest Phonegap, and, as I said, make sure the files being used on your phone are the latest ones. I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks I did make sure its the latest version i changed some text to be sure.

Comment: No It does not I tested it on my tablet also. very weird. works in chrome but not on android phones or tablets.

Comment: That's strange - I think you should post a bug to Phonegap if you dont figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction! `.val` should be `.html`. Please see the below code.

```
$('#my_name').html(personName);
```

add:

```
div id="my_name"
```