# Phonegap - developing and launching app on simulator

Tags: cordova, build, ios7, ios-simulator, relaunch

i'm developing using phonegap and when i want to launch the app in the ios simulator i do from terminal : `phonegap run ios`

but it takes a few seconds is really slow to launch and refresh the app again and again like this.

What i'm asking for is how to refresh app in simulator easly if possible quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the corresponding project blahblah.xcodeproj in XCode and supposedly you could run it from there, but I am having an impossible time getting it to detect changes to html and JS once in the simulator.

I have tried everything in this thread, [xcode 4 + phonegap ... not update JS upon build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486139/xcode-4-phonegap-not-update-js-upon-build) , but nothing seems to work.