# Cordova 4 Xcode 6 JS and HTML Refresh

Tags: xcode, cordova

I update Xcode to 6 and Cordova to 4.1.2, but changes in HTML or CSS are never visible. To see changes I have to modify directly file stored at {projectPath}/platform/ios/www (but 
Xcode update file stored at {projectPath}/www )

I have try to modify copy-www-build-step.sh like [XCode Build not updating JS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231767/xcode-build-not-updating-js-and-html) but without success.

If I make a cordova build ios, ok file are correctly copied but all signing configuration are lost.
I use Xcode for packaging and for submit.

May be there is a bug with latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i can modify html/css stored in Staging repository, but It's only a workaround ... and I think that file have to be copied from {projectPath}/www, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cordova prepare` when you make changes to your project's `www` code. This will copy it down to the Xcode staging versions. You can either do this manually, or you can set it up in Xcode as a build step. `cordova build ios` does this as part of the build step, which is why that command seems to work for you.

Comment: Yes i have try this but target configuration is erased (ie version number, build number and code signing configuration) after cordova release ios thx