# Cordova Build not updating index.html in ios platform directory

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I am using:

**Cordova 5.3.3**

**Xcode 6.2**

Working on the Cordova Tutorial:
https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/

modifying the the index.html running **cordova build ios** the www directory was *not updated* in the ios platform directory.

**cordova prepare** and **cordova prepare ios** are also not updating the www dir for ios when I update files in the root directory.

I searched and found this solution:

[22231767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231767/xcode-build-not-updating-js-and-html)

which references

> Find the file called copy-www-build-step.sh.
>   Mine was in [project_folder]/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh

However, in my installation I have a javascript file, not a shell script - *version perhaps*

> [project_folder]/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.js

and in that file:

```
var BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR = process.env.BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR,
    FULL_PRODUCT_NAME = process.env.FULL_PRODUCT_NAME,
    COPY_HIDDEN = process.env.COPY_HIDDEN,
    PROJECT_FILE_PATH = process.env.PROJECT_FILE_PATH;

var path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    shell = require('shelljs'),
    glob = require('glob'),
    srcDir = 'www',
    dstDir = path.join(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR, FULL_PRODUCT_NAME),
    dstWwwDir = path.join(dstDir, 'www');

if(!BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR) {
    console.error('The script is meant to be run as an Xcode build step and relies on env variables set by Xcode.');
    process.exit(1);
}

try {
    fs.statSync(srcDir);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Path does not exist: ' + srcDir);
    process.exit(1);
}

// Code signing files must be removed or else there are
// resource signing errors.
shell.rm('-rf', dstWwwDir);
shell.rm('-rf', path.join(dstDir, '_CodeSignature'));
shell.rm('-rf', path.join(dstDir, 'PkgInfo'));
shell.rm('-rf', path.join(dstDir, 'embedded.mobileprovision'));

// Copy www dir recursively
if(!!COPY_HIDDEN) {
    shell.mkdir('-p', dstWwwDir);
    shell.cp('-r', glob.sync(srcDir + '/**', { dot: true }), dstWwwDir);
} else {
    shell.cp('-r', srcDir, dstDir);
}

// Copy the config.xml file.
shell.cp('-f', path.join(path.dirname(PROJECT_FILE_PATH), path.basename(PROJECT_FILE_PATH, '.xcodeproj'), 'config.xml'),
    dstDir);
```

So it looks like `shell.cp('-r', srcDir, dstDir);` should be doing the copy work here. However the copy is not working in my instance.

Comment: are you using node 5? there are a few issues with tha version and cordova

Comment: yes, 5.0.0. Thanks for the tip. I'll see about downgrading.

Comment: Cordova 5.4.0 is out and fixes the issues with node 5

Comment: ha, and just as I got node 4.2.2 working. Thanks for the tip, this indeed was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You know what...not the answer you are hoping for, but I have noticed the same thing with the phonegap build service.  Sometimes I just have to run the build command more than once.

Maybe you have a file that the current build user is not allowed to write because perhaps an admin owns it.  Best of luck to you

Comment: I added some `console.log()` lines to the js file and saw no output, I suspect that the file is not being called due to some other configuration issue. I also ran it as sudo. I also edited the copy commands to use the **force** flag. `shell.cp('-rf', srcDir, dstDir);`

Answer (score 0):

as jcesarmobile stated there were issues with Cordova 5.3.3 and Node 5.0.0.

as I installed node with homebrew my fix was

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew unlink node
brew uninstall node
brew search node (gives the list of available version)
brew install homebrew/versions/node4-lts
```

At this point the ios build was successful, but also as jcesarmobile pointed out Cordova 5.4.0 has been released addressing this issue.